# Using prototype Extension Methods in Angular 2 template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How can I use a custom prototype in an Angular 2 template? Attached is the prototype I've written. This works perfectly in my unit test aswell as in any Angular 2 component typescript file. However if I attempt to use it in an Angular 2 html template file an exception is thrown stating that toUtcDate() is not a function of the specified date object.

I suspect I have to bootstrap this prototype into my app module somehow, but I'm currently at a loss with regard to how to proceed.

```
interface Date {
    toUtcDate(): string;
}

Date.prototype.toUtcDate = function(): string {
    var utcMonth = this.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    var utcDate = this.getUTCDate();

    var year = this.getUTCFullYear();
    var month = utcMonth < 10 ? '0' + utcMonth : utcMonth;
    var day = utcDate < 10 ? '0' + utcDate : utcDate;
    var hours = this.getUTCHours() < 10 ? '0' + this.getUTCHours() : this.getUTCHours();
    var minutes = this.getUTCMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + this.getUTCMinutes() : this.getUTCMinutes();
    var seconds = this.getUTCSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + this.getUTCSeconds() : this.getUTCSeconds();
    var milliseconds = this.getUTCMilliseconds() < 10 ? '0' + this.getUTCMilliseconds() : this.getUTCMilliseconds();
    return (year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + '.' + milliseconds + 'Z');
}
```

Comment: Problem 1: Shadowing JS built-in type. Problem 2: Using typescript, yet you operate on prototype, pretty bad if you ask me

Comment: Seems like you'd be better off with a pipe here.  Any reason you're going the route displayed? [Pipes info](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Comment: @JosephKing I guess I just wanted an extension method, but apparently that's not a thing in Angular 2? I rewrote this to a pipe now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of another way to achieve this, but here's a working example in Angular 9.

I extended the String object as follows (file = string.extensions.ts):

```
export { };

declare global {
    interface StringConstructor {
        isNullOrEmpty(value: string): boolean;
    }
}

if (!String.isNullOrEmpty) {
    String.isNullOrEmpty = function (value: string): boolean {
        if (value === undefined || value === null) {
            return true;
        }

        if(value != null && value.trim() === '') {
            
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

In your component you would need to import the string.extensions file (the path is important to get right):

```
import './yourPath/string.extensions.ts';
```

This makes it available in your component's TS file. E.g.

```
import './yourPath/string.extensions.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    const testString = 'test';
    console.log(String.isNullOrEmpty(testString)); //false

    const anotherTestString = null;
    console.log(String.isNulleOrEmpty(anotherTestString)); //true
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Finally the annoying bit - to get it working in the template. All you need to do is declare a public variable of the type you're extending. E.g.

```
String = String;
```

So the previous example component TS file would now look like this:

```
import './yourPath/string.extensions.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  String = String;
  stringToTest = null;

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

And to use it in your HTML template:

```
<div *ngIf="!String.isNullOrEmpty(stringToTest)">
  string was not empty or null
</div>
```